# Rearrangement of 8a-ethyl-1,3,4,8a-tetrahydronaphthalen-4a(2H)-ol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

really sorry for that previous post. I was actually half-asleep when I posted that q, hence the q was unclear. I am again reposti[image]ng that question

The answer is given as A. Can anyone please explain HOW ??

Comment: The last option is methylbenzene.

Comment: Cation rearrangement should be expected here, yet the answer (C) is strange to me; I'd assume (A).

Comment: Sorry Ivan Neretin, typo error-ans is A.-but HOW ???

Comment: @Aakhyat Singh: If you are still interested, for reliable mechanism for this type of rearrangement, see my answer to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116051/possible-nonclassical-ion-from-a-bicyclic-system/116057#116057).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer will be option **A**

First of all, name the carbon atom in the option A with $\ce{-Et}$ group attached to it as **x**, the $\ce{C}$ atom in the question with $\ce{-OH}$ attached to it as **y**, and the $\ce{C}$ atom *in the Question* with $\ce{-Et}$ attached to it as **z**

What will happen is, the $\ce{-OH}$ will get protonated forming $\ce{-OH2+}$. Concentrated acidic medium will facilitate formation of $\ce{H2O}$ by braking of bond between $\ce{C}$ and $\ce{O}$ in $\ce{C-OH2+}$ This will form a carbocation at the position **y** which will due to resonance reach the position **x**. Now, the $\ce{-Et}$ will do **alkyl shift** from **z** to **x**.

Now, a $\ce{C-H}$ bond at **x** will break and a $\ce{C=C}$ will form between the $\ce{C}$ atoms at **x** and **z**, *thus forming an aromatic compound as major product i-e option **A***

#

> Formation of $\ce{C+}$ is facilitated because of $\ce{conc. H2SO4 + heat}$ because $\ce{(conc. H2SO4 + heat)}$ acts as an *oxidising agent*, hence oxidising the $\ce{C}$ atom (or you may also think like, formation of $\ce{H2O}$ in a concentrate system will liberate *heat* thus its formation is favourable)

#

> *Alkyl shift* from **z** to **x** is favourable as it drives the reaction towards formation of a much stable *aromatic compound*