# Acid catalysed dehydration of alcohol with a bicyclo group

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, hydrocarbons, rearrangements

[image]

Pathway 1: Rate determining step is the formation of carbocation. In this pathway, a conjugated tertiary carbocation is generated as an intermediate.

[image]

Pathway 2: One of the resonance form of intermediate carbocation proceeds to produce a more stable  product (due to benzene ring) through alkyl migration. Though, the resonating form of carbocation is conjugated secondary carbocation which is less stable than the carbocation formed through pathway 1.

[image]

My questions are:

1- Is *tert*-butyl (don't know the correct term) migration possible in pathway- 2?

2- What are the major and minor products? Which factor will decide the major product: stability of final compound or the most stable intermediate?

Comment: The reactant/intermediate is clearly _not_ aromatic, but the product is. What about the $\ce{\Delta H, \Delta G}$ of reaction?

Comment: This reaction is under thermodynamic control. All of steps are reversible but the last step to form aromatic compound. Hence, aromatic compound is the major. The product from first path is still susceptible to protonate under acidic conditions.

Comment: " resonating form of carbocation is conjugated secondary carbocation which is less stable than the carbocation formed through pathway 1" - that's wrong on many levels.

Comment: I have never seen a migration of a t-butyl group before. That seems sterically problematic.

Comment: @Zhe Migratory aptitude might depend on the reaction. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migratory_aptitude) for  pinacol rearrangement the order is Hydride > $\ce{(CH3)3}$> Phenide > $\ce{C2H5}$ > $\ce{CH3}$ and per this [site](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/VirtTxtJml/rearrang.htm#:~:text=The%20migratory%20aptitude%20of%20various,%3E%201%C2%BA%2Dalkyl%20%3E%20methyl.) for Baeyer-Villiger rearrangement the order is 3º-alkyl > 2º-alkyl ~ benzyl ~ phenyl > 1º-alkyl > methyl (depends on electron density).

Comment: Therefore based on the electron density, t-butyl group should have a high migratory aptitude. But what factors can decide the migratory order for dehydration of alcohols?

Comment: That's fair, but we're not talking about _relative_ aptitude for migration. We're talking about whether elimination is faster than the shift. Also, thanks for the reference.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne What would be the outcome if t-butyl substituent is replaced by a substituent which cannot migrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pathway 2 is unlikely. The *tert*-butyl group stays put, i.e., it remains attached to the same carbon throughout the reaction. It is the rest of the molecule that rearranges. The mechanism of this reaction was demonstrated 70 years ago. Compare this reaction with [Possible nonclassical ion from a bicyclic system](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116051/possible-nonclassical-ion-from-a-bicyclic-system/116066#116066) on ChemSE. There is information at the link on labeling to elaborate the mechanism.

[image]

Comment: (a) I have gone through your linked answer (but could not access the references mentioned therein) and what I understood is that isotope labeling can decide the correct mechanism between the two discussed above. So, is it determined in the cited paper? (b) In your mechanism, is there any driving force between (1) and (2)? Or this is not important and final stable product decides it?

Comment: (a) In 1950 they didn't use isotopic labeling which is one way of testing the mechanism. They expected 4 but got 6 in the link. That result led to the spiro mechanism. (b) The cation 2 is resonance stabilized. The migratory aptitude of methyl is less than RCH2-.
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116051/possible-nonclassical-ion-from-a-bicyclic-system/116066#116066

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked for the driving force between (2) and (3).

Comment: There is not much difference (strain) between a 5- ans 6-membered ring. The delocalized cation is the same.in 2, 3 and 4. Aromatization drives the reaction.